# Crossreferencing single pages with cleveref and pdfpages

Tags: cross-referencing, appendices, pdfpages, cleveref

what I try to achieve is inserting multi-page pdfs in my Appendix organized in sections.

Inserting the `.pdf` files works the way I want it to.

Additionally I want every inserted page to be labeled and there's the problem.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}    %multilingual typesetting
    \setdefaultlanguage{english}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[unicode=true, colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdfpages}



 \newcounter{includepdfnumber}  %create counter for labeling every inserted pdf
 \newcounter{pdfpagenumber} %create counter for labeling every inserted pdf-page
 \newcounter{startpage} %create counter for incrementing startpage

 \newcommand{\includepdfwithlabel}[6]{% usage: \includepdfwithlabel{'startpage'}{'endpage'}{\chapter,\section...}{additional arguments}{'labelname'}{'filename'}
    \setcounter{pdfpagenumber}{0}
    \refstepcounter{includepdfnumber}           
    \setcounter{startpage}{#1}  %set startpage to argument #1
    \includepdf[pages=\thestartpage,#4,link,linkname=#5,pagecommand={#3\stepcounter{pdfpagenumber}\label{#5.\thepdfpagenumber}\large{#5-\theincludepdfnumber.\thepdfpagenumber}}]{#6} %
    \addtocounter{startpage}{1} %
    \includepdf[pages=\thestartpage-#2,#4,link,linkname=#5,pagecommand={\stepcounter{pdfpagenumber}\label{#5.\thepdfpagenumber}\large{#5-\theincludepdfnumber.\thepdfpagenumber}}]{#6} %

 }


 \begin{document}


    as seen in \cref{pdf1.1}\\
    as seen in \ref{pdf1.1}\\
    as seen in \cref{pdf1.2}\\
    as seen in \ref{pdf1.2}\\
    \\
    as seen in \cref{pdf2.1}\\
    as seen in \ref{pdf2.1}\\
    as seen in \cref{pdf2.2}\\
    as seen in \ref{pdf2.2}\\

    \newpage

    \begin{appendices}

    \includepdfwithlabel{1}{4}{\section{PDF A}}{height=0.6\textheight}{pdf1}{test.pdf}
    \includepdfwithlabel{1}{4}{\section{PDF B}}{height=0.6\textheight}{pdf2}{test.pdf}

    \end{appendices}

 \end{document}
```

The

```
\large{#5-\theincludepdfnumber.\thepdfpagenumber}
```

part is for debugging only.

The result I get when compiling is:

```
as seen in ??
as seen in A
as seen in ??
as seen in 1
as seen in ??
as seen in B
as seen in ??
as seen in 2
```

So `\ref` at least works, if still not correct, `\cref` doesn't do anything at all.

The way I would like it to have would be:

```
as seen in Appendix A, page 1
as seen in Appendix A, page 2
.
.
.
```

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 6):

See the (better?) approach with `zref` at the bottom.

There are several errors here:

1. `cleveref` should be loaded after `hyperref`, not somewhere in between
2. The `\label` call within the `pagecommand` option of `\includepdf` must be preceded by a `\refstepcounter`. Either this is the `\refstepcounter{includepdfnumber}` or the `\stepcounter{pdfpagenumber}`, the former would lead to identical labels, which would be 'wrong' (or better: useless)
3. `cleveref` needs information which name is to be referred, i.e. what should be printed by `\cref` or `\Cref` when a label is used for `pdfpagenumber`, so use `\crefname` and `\Crefname` in order to inform `cleveref` about this.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}    %multilingual typesetting
    \setdefaultlanguage{english}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage[unicode=true, colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{appendix}

\usepackage{cleveref}



\newcounter{includepdfnumber}  %create counter for labeling every inserted pdf
\newcounter{pdfpagenumber} %create counter for labeling every inserted pdf-page
\newcounter{startpage} %create counter for incrementing startpage


\crefname{pdfpagenumber}{file page}{file pages}
\Crefname{pdfpagenumber}{File page}{File pages}


\newcommand{\includepdfwithlabel}[6]{% usage: \includepdfwithlabel{'startpage'}{'endpage'}{\chapter,\section...}{additional arguments}{'labelname'}{'filename'}
  \setcounter{pdfpagenumber}{0}
  \refstepcounter{includepdfnumber}           
  \setcounter{startpage}{#1}  %set startpage to argument #1
  \includepdf[pages=\thestartpage,#4,link,linkname=#5,pagecommand={#3\refstepcounter{pdfpagenumber}\label{#5.\thepdfpagenumber}\large{#5-\theincludepdfnumber.\thepdfpagenumber}}]{#6} %
  \addtocounter{startpage}{1} %
  \includepdf[pages=\thestartpage-#2,#4,link,linkname=#5,pagecommand={\refstepcounter{pdfpagenumber}\label{#5.\thepdfpagenumber}\large{#5-\theincludepdfnumber.\thepdfpagenumber}}]{#6} %

}


\begin{document}
as seen in \cref{pdf1.1}

as seen in \ref{pdf1.1}

as seen in \cref{pdf1.2}

as seen in \ref{pdf1.2}

as seen in \cref{pdf2.1}

as seen in \ref{pdf2.1}

as seen in \cref{pdf2.2}

as seen in \ref{pdf2.2}


\begin{appendices}

  \includepdfwithlabel{1}{4}{\section{PDF A}}{height=0.6\textheight}{pdf1}{7.pdf}
  \includepdfwithlabel{1}{4}{\section{PDF B}}{height=0.6\textheight}{pdf2}{7.pdf}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

**The version with zref**

First, the section property is stored with `\zlabel` and the macro `\appref` extracts the information from which appendix the page reference is.

In order to create correct hyper anchors, `\theHpdfpagenumber` macro has to redefined as well in order to use the correct appendix number.

Since `hyperref` is used here anyway, I omitted a test whether `hyperref` is loaded at all.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}    %multilingual typesetting
\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage[user,counter,hyperref]{zref}
\usepackage[unicode=true, colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{appendix}

\makeatletter
% Storing the property section and adding it to the main property list
\zref@newprop{section}{\thesection}
\zref@addprop{main}{section}


\newcommand{\appref}[1]{%
  % Extracting the label
  \zref@ifrefundefined{#1}{%
  }{%
    \appendixname\ \zref@extract{#1}{section}, \hyperlink{\zref@extract{#1}{anchor}}{page \zref@extract{#1}{default}}%
  }%
}
\makeatother



\newcounter{includepdfnumber}  %create counter for labeling every inserted pdf

\newcounter{pdfpagenumber} %create counter for labeling every inserted pdf-page
% Providing correct hyper anchors since the pdfpagecounter is reset within every \includepdfwithlabel
\renewcommand{\theHpdfpagenumber}{appendix.\thesection.\thepdfpagenumber}
\newcounter{startpage} %create counter for incrementing startpage


\newcommand{\includepdfwithlabel}[6]{% usage: \includepdfwithlabel{'startpage'}{'endpage'}{\chapter,\section...}{additional arguments}{'labelname'}{'filename'}
  \setcounter{pdfpagenumber}{0}
  \refstepcounter{includepdfnumber}           
  \setcounter{startpage}{#1}  %set startpage to argument #1
  \includepdf[pages=\thestartpage,#4,link,linkname=#5,pagecommand={#3\refstepcounter{pdfpagenumber}\label{#5.\thepdfpagenumber}\zlabel{#5.\thepdfpagenumber}\large{#5-\theincludepdfnumber.\thepdfpagenumber}}]{#6} %
  \addtocounter{startpage}{1} %
  \includepdf[pages=\thestartpage-#2,#4,link,linkname=#5,pagecommand={\refstepcounter{pdfpagenumber}\label{#5.\thepdfpagenumber}\zlabel{#5.\thepdfpagenumber}\large{#5-\theincludepdfnumber.\thepdfpagenumber}}]{#6} %
}


\begin{document}
as seen in \appref{pdf1.1}

as seen in \ref{pdf1.1}

as seen in \appref{pdf1.2}

as seen in \appref{pdf1.2}

as seen in \appref{pdf2.1}

as seen in \ref{pdf2.1}

as seen in \appref{pdf2.2}

as seen in \ref{pdf2.2}


\begin{appendices}

  \includepdfwithlabel{1}{4}{\section{PDF A}}{height=0.6\textheight}{pdf1}{7.pdf}
  \includepdfwithlabel{1}{4}{\section{PDF B}}{height=0.6\textheight}{pdf2}{7.pdf}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And here is the code for `7.tex` used to generate `7.pdf` from:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\section{Beginning \jobname}
\blindtext[50]
\end{document}
```